# BlackBerry Webworks - Upgrade Push notification from Eval to Production

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, blackberry-webworks

I am developing application in BlackBerry Webworks. Push notifications is one of the feature of the app.

I have implemented Push notifications successfully by using Eval credentials and now when my application is complete, I want to upgrade Eval credentials to Production credentials which I have got from BlackBerry on request.

Issue I am facing is that Production credentials are not working like Eval credentials. Is there any code change I need to do to make it work?

Comment: How did you fix this? I implemented push in Android ported BB app, push was working fine before in Eval, after updating to production it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using any third-party library and using the pure Webworks API for client side and simple java code on server-side to send push messages. Here are the steps I need to follow:

Client side changes:

- server url (http://cpAPPID.pushapi.na.blackberry.com)
- app id
- port

Server side changes:

- auth ("Basic [encoded string from app-id:password]")
- app id
- push url (it should be https://pushapi.na.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest)